# How can open a detail view controller into a new view controller?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, uisplitviewcontroller, master-detail

I’m building a article reading iOS app.In iPad i’m using split view controller.
 Master view controller contains menu list like news,articles,media etc.
Clicking on Menu list data updates in detail view controller.Detail view controller(UITableView)contain list of articles and when I click on Article  it opens in the same view(Detail view controller),i’m unable to open that article in a new view controller.[image]

```
     - (void)viewDidLoad
       {
         [super viewDidLoad];
         NSLog(@"dshaghjdaS");
         UILabel *titleLabel = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20,10,0,20)];
         titleLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
          titleLabel.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
         titleLabel.text = @"Story";
        [self.navigationItem setTitleView:titleLabel];
           BOOL myBool = [self isNetworkAvailable];
          if (myBool)
           {
            @try {


              self.clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = NO;
               self.tableView.separatorColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:190/255.0 green:190/255.0   blue:190/255.0 alpha:1.0];
        // for displaying the previous screen lable with back button in details view controller
             UIBarButtonItem *backbutton1 = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@""   style:UIBarButtonItemStyleBordered target:nil action:nil];

          [[self navigationItem] setBackBarButtonItem:backbutton1];


         _Title1 = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
         _Author1 = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        _Images1 = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        _Details1 = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        _link1 = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        _Date1 = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

        NSData* data = [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:ysURL];
        NSLog(@"uuuuuuuuu%@",ysURL);
        NSArray *ys_avatars = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0  error:nil];

        if(ys_avatars){

            for (int j=0;j<ys_avatars.count;j++)
            {
                [_Title1 addObject:ys_avatars[j][@"title"]];
                [_Author1 addObject: ys_avatars[j][@"author"]];
                [_Images1 addObject: ys_avatars[j][@"featured_img"]];
                [_Details1 addObject:ys_avatars[j][@"content"]];
                [_link1 addObject:ys_avatars[j][@"permalink"]];
                NSString *newStr=[ys_avatars[j][@"date"] substringToIndex:[ys_avatars[j][@"date"] length]-3];
                [_Date1 addObject:newStr];
            }
        }
        else
        {
            NSLog(@"asd");

        }

    }
    @catch (NSException *exception) {

         UIAlertView *noConn = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"ERROR" message:@"Please   Check Your Internet Connection" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"ok", nil];
        [noConn show];

    }


  }
   else
   {
      UIAlertView *noConn = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"ERROR" message:@"Please Check  Your Internet Connection" delegate:self cancelButtonTitle:nil otherButtonTitles:@"ok", nil];
     [noConn show];

  }


} 




       - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
   {

      static NSString *Cellidentifier1 = @"ysIpadDetailTableViewCell";
    ysIpadDetailTableViewCell *cell1 = [tableView   dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:Cellidentifier1 forIndexPath:indexPath];

// Configure the cell...

   long row = [indexPath row];
   cell1.TitleLabel1.text = _Title1[row];
   cell1.AuthorLabel1.text = _Author1[row];
   cell1.Ddate1.text = _Date1[row];



    NSString *newUrl = [_Images1[indexPath.row]      stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
   dispatch_queue_t taskQ = dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0);
    dispatch_async(taskQ, ^{
    NSURL *Imageurl = [NSURL URLWithString:newUrl];
    NSData *data =  [NSData dataWithContentsOfURL:Imageurl];



    UIImage *images1 = [[UIImage alloc] initWithData:data];
    // Now the image will have been loaded and decoded and is ready to rock for the main thread
    dispatch_sync(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
        ysIpadDetailTableViewCell *updateCell =(id)[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
        if(updateCell)
            updateCell.ThumbImage1.image=images1;
        cell1.ThumbImage1.image=images1;

        });


    });

    return cell1;
```

}

Comment: can u add your DetailViewController code?

Comment: @Kathiravan Thanks, I have added my code,please check it once.

Comment: show your detail view code, you must have a tableview for showing the list i guess>

Comment: @Retro I have updated the code,please check it once.

Comment: @Daljeet this is delegate to show the data on cell, you need to show the -(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath delegate code

Comment: @Retro -(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{if([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"ShowDetails1"]){
ysIpadViewController *ysIpadDetailViewViewController=[segue destinationViewController];
NSIndexPath *myindexpath1 =[self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];   long row1=[myindexpath1 row];
ysIpadDetailViewViewController.DetailModal1= @[_Title1[row1],_Author1[row1],_Images1[row1],_Details1[row1],_link1[row1],_Date1[row1]];}}
I have just made the segue in storyboard,above is the code,right now article open in detail view controller,not in a new view controller.

Comment: Try my answer and reply me.

Comment: What about your detail view controller can u post some sample code?

Comment: Are u find the solution?

Comment: U told you created a segue right. from which controller to which?

Comment: I made a segue from Detail view contoller to another UIViewController.

Answer (score 0):

U need to implement UITableview Delegate method.

```
    -(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{

    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"ShowDetails1" sender:self];
}

-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    if([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"ShowDetails1"])
    {
        // Your code goes here
    }
}
```

Before that set UITableview delegate.

Comment: -(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender{if([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"ShowDetails1"]){ ysIpadViewController *ysIpadDetailViewViewController=[segue destinationViewController];NSIndexPath *myindexpath1 =[self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];long row1=[myindexpath1 row]; ysIpadDetailViewViewController.DetailModal1=@[_Title1[row1],_Author1[row1],_Images1[row1],_Details1[row1],_link1[row1],_Date‌​1[row1]];}} I have just made the segue in storyboard,above is the code,right now article open in detail view controller,not in a new view controller.

Comment: I think you did't get my question,anyways which code should be  in prepare for seague method.